# Email sender- recipient code error

Tags: c#, email, foreach, sender

Hi I have my project in 4 days and I got code from http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mGDnQchFZJg#!  , I could really use help, thanks in advance.

```
jet it gives me an error in foreach loop
```

Error   1   The name 's' does not exist in the current context

```
        MailMessage poruka = new MailMessage();
        poruka.From = new MailAddress(textBox4.Text);
        poruka.Subject = textBox2.Text;
        poruka.Body = textBox3.Text;
        foreach (string s in textBox1.Text.Split()) ;
        poruka.To.Add(s);


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);
        client.Host = "smtp.yahoo.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(poruka);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of your foreach, which means `s` is not in the scope when you add it to `poruka`. Change it to be like this:

```
foreach (string s in textBox1.Text.Split())
{
    poruka.To.Add(s);
}
```

This is the reason I, personally, always like to use braces and not inline my foreach's.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was to furious so i would not see that minor mistake.
Or i just dont have enough expirience jet :)